# Public/Private Key encryption/decryption with wallet

Tags: wallets, dapps, private-key, public-key, encryption

The following case:

There is a dApp in place, connected with a wallet (e.g. Metamask). Wallets usually don't offer public/priate key encryption/decryption.

I want to decrypt a message for the owner of an address, using the recipient's public key. The recipient then decrypt's the message using his private key. However, the wallets today are limited to sing messages.

Is there a possibility to encrypt/decrypt messages using today's wallets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metamask provides: [eth_decrypt](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-decrypt) and [eth_getEncryptionPublicKey](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-getencryptionpublickey).

Together with [eth-sig-util](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util) should help encrypt and decrypt messages.

Comment: Hi @Ismael. Thank you very much. That's great news. How can I use It in a Dapp? I usually use WalletConnect to connect my Dapp.

Comment: Okay, WalletConnect supports etc_decrypt and get_EncryptionPublicKey if supported by wallet:
https://discord.com/channels/492410046307631105/833628540456140821/905050546904399892

Comment: @user66732 The links from metamask docs provide an example. I looked around if there's a specification but so far I haven't found an EIP. I hope it will be standard EIP and other wallets will implement it.